# Javascript: Anti-spam Automoderator (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, command, bots, discord, discord.js

I am coding a multipurpose Discord bot to replace some of the more minor ones, and I am looking for a piece of code for a feature that recognizes repeated messages or messages sent in a very short time period (let's say 5000ms).

Here is what could be used to implement this idea.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
//let's use something like a spam variable for 10 or more messages sent within 5000ms
if(message.content === spam) {
    message.reply("Warning: Spamming in this channel is forbidden.");
    console.log(message.author.username + " (" + message.author.id + ") has sent 10 messages or more in 5 seconds in " + message.channel.name + ".");
  }
});
```

For reference, I also made a feature that deletes messages, using a ~delete [n] command. It looks like this:

```
//this will only delete one message in the channel, the most recent one.
    message.delete(1000);
//1000 represents the timeout duration. it will only delete one message, regardless of the value.

//we can delete multiple messages with this, but note it has to come before the reply message.
    message.channel.bulkDelete(11);
```

I was thinking of somehow combining the delete command with recognizing spam messages. If you have any ideas, that would be perfect.

Comment: You can actually change your console.log message a bit. With ES6 your can change you console.log() line from 

`message.author.username + " (" + message.author.id + ") has sent 10 messages or more in 5 seconds in " + message.channel.name + "."`

to

`\`${message.author.username} (${message.author.id}) has send 10 messages or more in 5 seconds in ${message.channel.name}.\``

Comment: that's much simpler. thanks

Comment: You are welcome =D

I think I have a solution, just let me test it!

Comment: Also, is your bot exclusive to only one guild? Tf it is, you might be able to make an array for each guild member on startup (Even though its not the best idea)

Comment: yes it is exclusive to only one guild as of now. and i am looking forward to that anti-spam solution XD

Comment: LOL Ill try to get it working. Time to get googling'

Comment: Do you know how to delete / get messages from one user?

Comment: Well, yes, if you have a specific message in mind. Just use an if statement that looks for both the user's id and the message. Inside of the if statement call for a delete.

`client.on('message', message => {
  // If the word(s) or phrase is found anywhere in their message, from user with that id, and matches "message"
  if (message.content.includes("message") && message.author.id !== ("PUT ID HERE")) {
});`

or replace the if line with (only if the message starts with it)

`if(message.content.startsWith("message")) && message.author.id !== ("PUT ID HERE")) {`

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work. I'm still trying the stupid-array method, which I need to collect the last ten messages for a specific user (to get their time of post) by a UserResolvable, and checking via the setInterval() function.

As of writing this post, I realized I could use message.author.id to get the author of the post, but I have no idea to delete 10 messages from a _specific_ user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
const usersMap = new Map();
const LIMIT = 7;
const DIFF = 5000;

client.on('message', async(message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    
    if(usersMap.has(message.author.id)) {
        const userData = usersMap.get(message.author.id);
        const { lastMessage, timer } = userData;
        const difference = message.createdTimestamp - lastMessage.createdTimestamp;
        let msgCount = userData.msgCount;
        console.log(difference);

        if(difference > DIFF) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            console.log('Cleared Timeout');
            userData.msgCount = 1;
            userData.lastMessage = message;
            userData.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
                console.log('Removed from map.')
            }, TIME);
            usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData)
        }
        else {
            ++msgCount;
            if(parseInt(msgCount) === LIMIT) {

               message.reply("Warning: Spamming in this channel is forbidden.");
              message.channel.bulkDelete(LIMIT);
               
            } else {
                userData.msgCount = msgCount;
                usersMap.set(message.author.id, userData);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        let fn = setTimeout(() => {
            usersMap.delete(message.author.id);
            console.log('Removed from map.')
        }, TIME);
        usersMap.set(message.author.id, {
            msgCount: 1,
            lastMessage : message,
            timer : fn
        });
    }
})
```